# python installation issue with adalm pluto - typeError

Tags: python-3.x, pluto

Adalm Pluto connected to laptop running Linux Mint 20.
Trying to run a very basic Python script and getting an error "TypeError: 'Context' object is not callable".

Did have an earlier error in that Python could not locate the iio.py module but this was fixed by updating the $PYTHONPATH variable in the bashrc script.

Everything else tested seems to work correctly. The Pluto itself looks to be working fine and does an excellent job connected to SATSAGEN on Windows 10.

Don't know how to progress. Any pointers much appreciated.

Python code:

```
# Import library
import adi
# Create radio object
sdr = adi.Pluto(uri="ip:192.168.2.1")
# Configure properties
sdr.rx_rf_bandwidth = 4000000
# Get data
data = sdr.rx()
```

TerminalOutput:

```
bob@SamsungLaptop:~$ python "/home/bob/Documents/Python scripts/Pluto/pluto_check_installation.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/bob/Documents/Python scripts/Pluto/pluto_check_installation.py", line 8, in <module>
data = sdr.rx()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyadi_iio-0.0.7-py3.8.egg/adi/rx_tx.py", line 250, in rx
return self.__rx_complex()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyadi_iio-0.0.7-py3.8.egg/adi/rx_tx.py", line 171, in __rx_complex
self._rx_init_channels()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyadi_iio-0.0.7-py3.8.egg/adi/rx_tx.py", line 127, in _rx_init_channels
self.__rxbuf = iio.Buffer(self._rxadc, self.__rx_buffer_size, False)
File "/home/bob/libiio/bindings/python/iio.py", line 1016, in __init__
self._ctx = device.ctx()
TypeError: 'Context' object is not callable
```

The above Python code was also run in Interpreter mode and all commands up to the last line were accepted.

Other example scripts have been attempted but the line containing 'sdr.rx()' appears to be causing the error.
Communications with the Pluto seem to be functional (e.g. having set the rf bandwidth as above, this can be checked with a print command. Also, communication is possible via usb connection or an ip address or via ssh or via PuTTY).
The libiio library seems OK (e.g. typing 'iio_info -s' or 'iio_info -u Pluto.local' are working.
The pyadi library seems OK (e.g. the import of adi works without error)

INSTALLATION:
A) Linux Mint 20 with Cinnammon GUI    (Kernel updated from v5.4 to v5.8 to solve another issue).
B) libiio, libadad9361-iio and pyadi-iio all generated from sources and installed as per Chapter 5 of PySDR (https://pysdr.org/content/pluto_intro.html). The above Python example is provided in the same chapter as a means to check the installation.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using v0.21 of libiio, with python bindings.  Somehow, between version 0.19 (or maybe 0.20, I can't get at the source code right now) and 0.21, the usage of weakref was removed, which introduces this bug.  (See: https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio/issues/648)  I guess that means chances are good that this SO question will quickly become irrelevant.

Try using 0.19 or you can consider two different ways of fixing the problem by editing /home/bob/libiio/bindings/python/iio.py

The first is to revert to how things were happening in v0.19 by adding the relevant lines back in yourself.

Add "import weakref" after the line "import abc":

```
import abc
import weakref
```

Change the line in class Device's **init** method to:

```
self.ctx = weakref.ref(ctx)
```

This will work for the purposes of that demo code, however I don't think it's entirely correct, because the weakref is sort of defeating the purpose of the buffer object creating a new reference.  From the v0.21 code:

```
self._ctx = device.ctx()
# Holds a reference to the corresponding IIO Context. This ensures that
# every iio.Buffer object is destroyed before its corresponding IIO Context.
```

Because of the weakref, there's no ensuring that the object sticks around if non-weak references to it are deleted.  In that sense, you could try just replacing all "ctx()" with "ctx".  There should be 3 instances in v0.21.  That also works for me, and is my preferred fix for now.

caveat:  There could be less-apparent problems involved, if it's something the code maintainer is going back and forth on, so either fix may just be playing "whack-a-mole."

Comment: Seems like the maintainer is working on that fix: https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio/compare/master...tfcollins-py-weak-ref

Answer (score 0):

Mark H,
My understanding of this has improved a lot since I posted - but I'm pretty sure that you have nailed the issue. I'm going to give a bit of detail in the hope that it might help others as the context is important.

My objective was to get a working environment on Linux that catered for 1) Adalm Pluto, 2) Python control using pyadi-iio and 3) GNU Radio. If like me you want all three it adds extra dimensions.

The solution I've got to (thanks to Travis at Analog Devices) was to make two changes - replace a file and change it's name -
A) Replace the'iio.py' file with the weakref version (from link below)
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/analogdevicesinc/libiio/tfcollins-py-weak-ref/bindings/python/iio.py
B) Rename the file to something like 'weak_iio.py'
C) Go into the pyadi-iio folder (ADI) and edit two files ( "rx_tx.py", and "context_manager.py"). The single line in each - 'import iio' - needs to be changed to  'import weak_iio as iio'

This has allowed several Python pyadi-iio scripts now work as well, but without impacting the working GNU Radio.

I have not yet hit a python / pyadi script that does not work, however the test script that Travis suggested (below) still fails on the last line, so there may be other issues I have yet to hit.

```
import adi
sdr = adi.Pluto('ip:pluto.local')
print(dir(sdr._ctx))
print(sdr._ctx.name)
print(dir(sdr._rxadc))
print(dir(sdr._rxadc.ctx()))

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "travis_test2.py", line 6, in <module>
print(dir(rx._rxadc.ctx()))
NameError: name 'rx' is not defined
```

A virtual environment was created with pipenv, and this script ran without error inside of that. So, as of now, I don't know how important this script error is but the above changes have allowed me to progress.

I'm also linking to another thread that has further detail.
https://ez.analog.com/sw-interface-tools/f/q-a/534115/pyadi-iio-operation-in-gnuradio-3-8/404723#404723

Thanks again

Comment: Nice progress!  I didn't mention the iio naming conflict (which I also find frustrating), because you didn't bring it up in your question and it wasn't affecting the execution, so I assumed you had already dealt with that somehow.  Thanks for posting your fix to that issue, though, because I'm sure a lot of people are going to trip over that.  Speaking of gotchas for PlutoSDR, the env. variable to set to expand the tunable range and max sampling rate changed to:  "fw_setenv compatible ad9364"  as of fw v0.32 (see https://github.com/analogdevicesinc/plutosdr-fw/issues/54).

Comment: I'm having a little trouble following the traceback, because it says line 6 has "print(dir(rx._rxadc.ctx()))" but the script has "print(dir(sdr._rxadc.ctx()))".  At any rate, the problem there is that the ctx object in this case is *not* a weakref, and doesn't have the __call__ method like weakref does (lets you add () after the object).  I've posted my concerns on the github issue mentioned in my post.  You can see in class Device that he's setting self.ctx = ctx, whereas before he was using weakref.  Now he's just moved usage of weakref to the Buffer class (not sure why).

Comment: Mark H - Very much appreciated the feeback. 
On point 1, this is helpful as I wasn't aware and apparently won't be published just yet!
On point 2, way beyond my current knowledge, but catching up every day. I'm currently working through the PySDR book and really enjoying that. Of course this needs the pyadi-iio library, but I'm not having any issues with performance so far.
Thanks again for the info.